# Using "as" to connect sentences or omitting it to create a relative clause

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, relative-clauses

I have the following sentence:

> We take advantage of these approaches as described in the following section.

Or is it better to omit "as":

> We take advantage of these approaches described in the following section.

I am not not quite clear how the meaning change with/without 'as' in this case. Any insights?

Comment: Even if you'd done some research, that would be a question of style choice.

Comment: Best there would be "We take advantage of *those* approaches described in the following section" but what did your dictionaries and search engines leave unclear, please?